# How do I make python wait while processing other code?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this piece of code:

```py
import time

def printAtInterval():
    print('text')
    time.sleep(60 - time.time() % 60)

def getCommand():
    command = input()
    if command == 'help':
        print('something')

while True:
    getCommand()
    printAtInterval()
```

The problem with this code is obvious, I can't input anything while the process is waiting for the time to elapse.
I'd like to have them both working at the same time.

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941851/grab-user-input-asynchronously-and-pass-to-an-event-loop-in-python

Comment: Try to look to `threading` module. Your question is about parallel computing.

Comment: The other comments are correct, however for this specific task I would recommend you to use https://pypi.org/project/schedule/